# SQL code for testing multiple values in table

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains multiple `Rqst_id`s with unique `Act_id`s for Risk. I am looking to obtain sql code to find the `req_id`s in which the `Risk` value are ALL 'approved'.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
Rqst_id Act_id  Risk

3530    24624   Abstain
3530    24714   Abstain
3733    24726   Approve
3733    24729   Null
4310    27473   Approve
4401    28444   Approve
4676    30797   Approve
5069    32003   Approve
4946    32062   Approve
4946    32063   Approve
4779    32424   Approve
4779    32425   Null
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Rqst_id,RISK
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Risk='Approve'
```

Comment: The OP wanted Rqst_ids where *all* Risks for the Rqst_id were Approve.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Rqst_id
FROM Table1
WHERE Rqst_id NOT IN (
    SELECT Rqst_id
    FROM Table1
    WHERE risk != "Approve"
      OR risk IS NULL
    );
```

This will get you the req_id's that don't have any risk != "Approve".

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e40a1d/7)</kbd>

Comment: It won't handle NULLs. In the OP's example, 4779 is returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT rqst_id FROM my_table t
WHERE rqst_id NOT IN (
    SELECT rqst_id FROM my_table WHERE risk IS NULL OR risk <> 'Approve'
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be risk instead of rqst_id in inner query ?

Comment: Yes, it has been fixed.

Comment: `"Approve"` is a column name in (standard) SQL, not a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.reqst_id
from the_table t1
where risk = 'Approve'
group by t1.reqst_id
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from the_table t2
                   where t2.reqst_id = t1.reqst_id);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/915fc/3

If you also need the complete row (including the act_id), you can use a (standard SQL) window function:

```
select reqst_id, act_id, risk
from (
  select reqst_id, 
         act_id, 
         risk,
         count(*) over (partition by reqst_id) as total_count, 
         sum(case when risk = 'Approve' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by reqst_id) as approve_count
  from risks
) t 
where total_count = approve_count;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/915fc/5

Note that with that solution a single reqst_id will be returned multiple times if there are multiple rows.

The solution with the window function might actually be faster, because only a single scan over the table is needed.